# Spring-Boot 1.5.10.RELEASE / JBoss-EAP7.1.1 Remote Client

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jboss-eap-7

The following code will run and produce correct results (Gets a list of messages from a JMS QUEUE using a Queue Browser Object) when run as a regular standalone "hello-world style" java application.

It has 1 maven dependency for the jboss-client.jar (v7.1.1).

The same code fails with the below exception when run in a Spring-Boot (1.5.10.RELEASE) Application with the same maven dependency for the jboss-client.jar (v7.1.1).

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("EAP-7.1.1: Get Browser Messages Test");

String fullQueueName = "jms/queue/QUEUEREPORTING.REPORT_DATA_IMPORT_FORM_DEADLETTER";
String serverName = "deap7c55n5lxv";

Properties queueBrowserProps = new Properties();
queueBrowserProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
queueBrowserProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote+http://" + serverName + ":8180");
queueBrowserProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL , "user");
queueBrowserProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS , "pass");

InitialContext initialContext;

Connection connection = null; 
QueueBrowser browser = null;
Session session = null;
Enumeration<?> messages = null;

try {

    initialContext = new InitialContext(queueBrowserProps);

    Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup(fullQueueName); 
    ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory)initialContext.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"); 
    connection = cf.createConnection("user","pass");
    session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); // Throws Error here when run in Spring-Boot
    browser = session.createBrowser(queue); 
    messages = browser.getEnumeration();

    while (messages.hasMoreElements()) {
        Object msg = messages.nextElement(); 
        sb.append("MessageClass: " + msg.getClass());

        if (msg instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) msg;
            sb.append("MessageText: " + tm.getText());
        }
    }


} catch (NamingException | JMSException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    sb.append(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
}   

sb.append("EAP-7.1.1: Test END");
return sb.toString();
```

The Exception:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:757)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:265)
    at com.mitchell.enterprise.jmsviewer.controllers.HomeController.test(HomeController.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.mitchell.enterprise.headerfilter.filter.ServletHeaderFilter.doFilter(ServletHeaderFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:787)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:755)
    ... 68 more
```

I am trying to troubleshoot what is causing the Connection Object to not be connected when the code runs in Spring-Boot. Any ideas would be appreciated...

Has anyone else been successful making the session from the connection using the jboss-client.jar and EAP7.1.1 from a Spring-Boot app?

Comment: The error "AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers." is common since it comes up just about anytime a client fails to connect to a server for any reason. see this thread(https://developer.jboss.org/thread/266416) for more details on how to configure your connector(s) properly in that situation.
Maybe need to expose the port publicly via -p 8180:8180

Comment: Anup - yes it's very generic error. The same code running independently of Spring-Boot does connect fine. as does an older version of the jboss-client.jar running in Spring-Boot. Seems like there is something going on between dependencies of Spring-Boot and jboss-client.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with a transient dependency conflict between Spring-Boot and the jboss-client.jar's version of io/netty - you must make sure the jboss-client.jar version of io/netty is being used. The io/netty classes needed to be excluded from the spring-cloud-starter-eureka dependency. More specifically:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.netflix.ribbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>ribbon</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.netflix.ribbon</groupId>
  <artifactId>ribbon</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```